# Improve performance of selects and inserts both

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, sqlbulkcopy

I have a heap table in which I have a column known as BatchId. I am inserting on it using SqlbulkCopy (with tablock and batch size of 50k) and performance is very decent. I am usually inserting for a whole batch of around 1 M rows with same batchId. I need to create an index on batchId for "selects" but I don't want to compromise my insert performance. What is the recommended approach here (clustered index/ non clustered index/ partitioning on batchId or something else), does this help that during one insert I have all the rows with same batchId?

Comment: The only way you'll know is to experiment and see which is the most acceptable. You're already using tablock to utilise parallelism. If the inserts don't happen concurrently with other use then create the index you need and drop it just for the bulk load? Make sure you also use instant file initialisation and size your DB / log files in advance to avoid growth during inserts.

Comment: And have you tagged sql2008 in error or are you actually using it in production still? Time to ask your DBA to upgrade... ;-)

Comment: using 2016 only, Would dropping and recreating index every time not cause performance issues?

Comment: The answer is the usual "it depends". Dropping an index is very quick. Building an index obv depends on its size but, if you only do inserts in off-peak times and can utilise it for hours then it's worth the trade off. You'll need to experiment, in my experience it's always the better trade off. If the table is large engough you could consider partiioning, but that won't really help if the majority of reads are for the newly loaded data.

Comment: Inserts are more frequent, usually it takes around 10s for 1 M rows on heap, but selects are also needed. I am using archiving strategy now where after every batch job finished, I move the rows to a highly indexed table which take around 3 minutes per batch

Comment: How about using CDC or Change Tracking? Insert into your heap as normal, use CT to syphon data off to an indexed table for querying. All depends on what latency you can tolerate.

Comment: seems like a good idea as it is asynchronous also.

Comment: Certainly worth looking into I would say. I've compiled a list as an answer for you, hope it helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230004/discussion-between-sttu-and-deepak-mishra).

Comment: Have you actually tested bulk insert on a clustered index?

Answer (score 1):

Possible ideas would include

- Creating suitable index(es) only at times when necessary and dropping for bulkload performance
- Checking log file and data files are sized in advance to avoid file growth
- Split data file into multiple physical files to utilise asynchronous writes to separate volumes
- Partition the table, depending on data use case
- Implement change tracking / CDC, retain fast inserts and syphon data off asynchronously using built in reliable methods to make data available separately for querying.